# Pass environment variable from host to DockerOperator in Airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, dockeroperator

I currently have a Docker container with a python image where I run the cronjobs. I use a docker compose file to run it, where I pass the tokens from the host (my Macbook) to the container as environment variables.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: py-cont
    build: .
    environment:
      GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN: ${GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN}
```

I would like to migrate the cronjobs to AirFlow (run using the docker-compose file from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.3/docker-compose.yaml)) where I want to use the DockerOperator, but I do not know how to pass the environment variables from the host, to achieve exactly what my docker-compose did.

This is my DAG, which throws the KeyError in the AirFlow logs when run, trying to fetch the env var that doesn't exist (the var is sourced on the host, confirmed by echo-ing it):

```
DockerOperator(
dag=dag,
task_id='refresh_tickers',
image='mypythonimage',
api_version='auto',
auto_remove=True,
environment={
'GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN': os.environ['GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN']
},
command='echo $GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN',
docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375',
network_mode='bridge',
)
```

I'm new to AirFlow, and it could be I am misunderstanding what the host in this case is, is it one of the many containers defined in the docker-compose, and not my macbook? This would be confusing, because the volumes parameter to DockerOperator mounts my local (Macbook) filepath to the container with no problems.

Thanks.

Comment: `the var is sourced on the host` ? Did environment variables _was set in the environment_ airflow started from? `confirmed by echo-ing it` so it is set _in an interactive shell_. Who cares - what is important, _was_ it set when airflow _started_? It wasn't, hence your problem, so you have to figure out other ways of bringing the information to the process.

Comment: It was already set when airflow started.

Comment: it is quite logic when you think about it. Airflow code is run in the Airflow containers, but because you use DockerOperator, the mount is related to where your docker container will run, which is your machine.

However, instead of getting the secret from an env var on your laptop or Airflow container, I would use [variables in Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is checking if you have the env variable exists in your host:

```bash
echo $GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN
```

Second step is adding the env variable to all the scheduler and all the workers containers, to do that you need to update the docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.3}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    ...
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN: ${GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN}
```

Last step is checking if the env variable exists in the worker container:

```bash
docker-compose exec airflow-worker bash -c 'echo "$GOOGLE_ADS_TOKEN"'
```